# Convex combinations of product states

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Is it true that the set of convex combinations of product states on a tensor product of C*-algebras is weak*-dense in the set of all states on said tensor product?

Answer (score -1):

No. Not even in the finite-dimensional case.

Let $A=B=M_2(\mathbb C)$. We can identify $$\tag1 A\otimes B\simeq M_4(\mathbb C)$$ via the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Note that we don't need to be careful about the topology here, since these are finite-dimensional algebras and so they have a unique locally convex topology.

The states on $M_2(\mathbb C)$ are of the form $\operatorname{Tr}(H\cdot)$, with $H$ positive and trace one. Then
$$\tag2
\operatorname{Tr}(H\,\cdot\,)\otimes\operatorname{Tr}(K\,\cdot\,)=\operatorname{Tr}((H\otimes K)\,\cdot\,)
$$
(the uniqueness of the trace up to a scalar multiple guarantees the equality $(2)$.
So the question is whether the positive elements of the form $\sum_j t_j(a_j\otimes b_j)$ with $a_j,b_j\geq0$ and $t_j$ convex coefficients, are dense in the positive elements in $M_4(\mathbb C)$. As the state space in a finite-dimensional C$^*$-algebra is compact, and the convex hull of compact sets is compact in finite dimension, density here means equality. And [the answer is no](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/43138/positive-elements-in-tensor-products/43198#43198), even if we consider sums and not just convex combinations.